# Machine model for functional programming

Tags: functional-programming

I've read somewhere that the current machine model is not quite fit for functional programming. So what is the limitations of the current machine model? Has a more suitable machine model been developed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Landin's [SECD machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SECD_machine) was one of the first designed to evaluate lambda calculus expressions. Ager et al. cover other abstract and virtual machines designed to do same in their paper "[A Functional Correspondence between Evaluators and Abstract Machines](http://www.brics.dk/RS/03/13/BRICS-RS-03-13.pdf)".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was developed. Here's an article on [Lisp Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine).

Comment: Lisp machines were optimized to run Lisp programs, but weren't machine models. Furthermore, from what I understand, they were still sequential. A suitable machine model for (pure) functional programming shouldn't be sequential.